# setting different access for different module

Tags: zend-framework, module, acl

I want set different access for different modules.

I tried out

```
$this->allow($role, $module, $controller, $action);
```

or

```
$this->allow($role, $module . ':' . $controller, $action);
```

But this does not seem to work.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To setup acl correctly you need to define **roles**, **resources** and **permissions**.

E.g.

```
$this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guests'));

$this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('default'))
     ->add(new Zend_Acl_REsource('default:index'), 'default');

$this->allow('guests', 'default:index', array('index', 'error'));
```

This is a module based structure. So first you define a role. Then you define the module resource which is default. Index is the IndexController. And finally you set the actions that user of type guest should be able to access as array.

The second line of code in your question seems to be ok so there might be a problem anywhere else. Check out some resources:

Documentation: [**Zend_Acl**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.introduction.html)

How To: [**Zend Framework 1.8 tutorial 5 zend_acl with zend_auth and controller plugin**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6qsSnLfcmE)

Comment: thanx, but i have prob yet!
 there is around 100 controll in my proj, by your way i have to add all of them with this code `->add(new Zend_Acl_REsource('default:index'), 'default');` because i`m checking current page access with this code ** if ($this->_acl->isAllowed($this->_currentRole, $this->_module .':'. $this->_controller, $this->_action)) ** or ** if ($this->_acl->isAllowed($this->_currentRole, $this->_controller, $this->_action)) ** it`s terrific!

Comment: Yes, when you want to control permissions you have to define it like in my answer. you can setup a acl library like describe in the how to